# Rails - Adding a command line script to my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, twitter

I don't like asking noobie questions but I've spent more time than I care to admit googling and trying to figure out this simple process. I'm trying to use the twitter gem to post tweets in my app's views.

I have this script that works when I run it on the command line, but I don't know how to access the data on my views. I have the gem installed. I tried adding this code to my controller but it still doesn't let me call it in the view.

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twitter'

client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
  config.consumer_key        = "(redacted)"
  config.consumer_secret     = "(redacted)"
  config.access_token        = "(redacted)"
  config.access_token_secret = "(redacted)"
end

client.search("help", :result_type => "recent").take(3).each do |tweet|
  puts tweet.text

end
```

If anyone can point me in the right direction, that would be great.

Comment: Post tweets in app's *views*? Sounds like a horrible idea. Why would you want to do that? View should only generate output to present to the user, nothing else. Can you explain more about what you want to do? When do you want to post to Twitter, when the page is loading or when a user makes a certain action?

Comment: I'm a beginner and I'm just trying to practice using rails and APIs. Can you explain why that would be a horrible idea?

Comment: I already did: "View should only generate output to present to the user, nothing else". Rails is built on [MVC philosophy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller), and separation of concerns is the primary... err... concern. You don't do anything from a view that is outside direct interaction with the user.

Comment: Hmm, I just read MichaelA's answer, then reread your question. If you want to *get and display* tweets and not *post* them as you wrote, that's the pattern: you prepare stuff in your model or controller (I would have voted to put it in the non-database-bound model, but meh), then pass it to the view to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I'll post some (untested) code that might help set you in the right direction. It's not the best way to do it, as it's not very flexible, but it should do what your example does. Make sure add the Twitter gem to your Gemfile and bundle install. Create a Ruby class called TweetsFromAccount. Saving it in the /lib directory works just fine.

```
class TweetsFromAccount

  def initialize
    @client = Twitter::REST::Client.new do |config|
      config.consumer_key        = "(redacted)"
      config.consumer_secret     = "(redacted)"
      config.access_token        = "(redacted)"
      config.access_token_secret = "(redacted)"
    end
  end

  def recent_tweets(quantity)
    array_of_tweets = []

    @client.search("help", :result_type => "recent").take(quantity).each do |tweet|
      array_of_tweets << tweet.text
    end
  end

end
```

In the controller, create a new TweetsFromAccount object and assign it to an instance variable, @tweets. Create an additional instance variable set the value of @tweets.recent_tweets(3). This should fetch the 3 most recent tweets.

```
def show
  # other stuff

  @tweets = TweetsFromAccount.new
  @array_of_tweets = @tweets.recent_tweets(3)
end
```

Then in your view, just iterate over @array_of_tweets.

```
<ul>
  <% @array_of_tweets.each do |tweet| %>
    <li><%= tweet %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```